# Translations between S4 and S5 modal logics

Tags: lo.logic, modal-logic

$\textbf{Question}$: Is there a translation from $\textbf{S5}$ modal logic to $\textbf{S4}$ such that

$$\text{If} \hspace{0.3cm}  \textbf{S5} \vdash F \hspace{0.3cm} \text{then } \hspace{0.3cm} \textbf{S4} \vdash F'$$

where $F'$ is formed from $F$ by applying a suitable translation $\hspace{0.2cm}'$?

I take it that every theorem of $\textbf{S4}$ is a theorem of $\textbf{S5}$, the former being a sublogic of the latter, the translation of $\textbf{S4}$ into $\textbf{S5}$ thereby being trivial.

My interest in this question comes from considering Goedel's translation of Intuitionistic propositional logic into $S4$, and how that translation would look in $S5$, but since $S4$ is a sublogic of $\textbf{S5}$, there would be only a trivial translation. However, I don't know of a translation of $\textbf{S5}$ into $\textbf{S4}$. If there is a particular reason why such a translation does not or could not exist, I would be interested to know.

---

$\textbf{S5}$ is characterised by the axioms for classical propositional logic alongside the $\textbf{Necessitation Rule}$:   If $A$ is a theorem, then so is $□A$), plus the axioms below. $\textbf{S4}$ is characterised by the axioms for classical propositional logic plus the the Necessitation Rule and the $\textbf{K,T, 4}$ axioms below (as usual, $\Diamond A := \neg \thinspace\Box \neg A$):

$$\textbf{K}: \Box(A\to B)\to(\Box A\to\Box B);$$
$$\textbf{T}: \Box A \to A$$,

and either:

$$\textbf{5}: \Diamond A\to \Box\Diamond A;$$
or both:
$$\textbf{4}: \Box A\to\Box\Box A,$$ and
$$\textbf{B}: A\to\Box\Diamond A.$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As written, there is a trivial such translation: just put $F'=\top$ for all formulas $F$.

Assuming you actually wanted to formulate the condition as “if and only if” rather than just “if”, a simple such translation is provided by
$$\mathrm{S5}\vdash A\iff\mathrm{S4}\vdash\Diamond\Box A.$$

Comment: I don't understand why a formula $A$ of $S4$ does not simply translate as $A$ in $S5$, given that $S4$ is a sublogic of $S5$, so that $S4 \vdash \Diamond \Box A$ translates as $S5 \vdash  \Diamond \Box A$.

Comment: I don’t understand the point of your comment. As it happens, $\mathrm{S4}\vdash\Diamond\Box A$ if and only if $\mathrm{S5}\vdash\Diamond\Box A$, but the question asks for a translation of S5 into S4, not for a translation of S5 into S5, so why would I mention $\mathrm{S5}\vdash\Diamond\Box A$?

Comment: I thought a translation of $S5$ into $S4$ would mean only $S5 ⊢ A\Rightarrow S4 ⊢ A'$, for some translation function $'$, and not the converse, as you stated.

Comment: Well but then its existence would be trivial between any pair of logics, as I wrote in the beginning of my answer, hence it would not be a useful concept.

Comment: I wasn't taking into account trivial translation functions. What I meant to say is that I thought a non-trivial translation of S5 into S4 would mean only$S5⊢A⇒S4⊢A′$, for some non-trivial translation function $′$, and not the converse, as you stated.

Comment: How does the translation you provided above work for the connectives? Is it simply  $S5⊢A \circ B \Rightarrow S4 ⊢\Diamond \Box A \circ \Diamond \Box B$, for binary connectives $\{\land, \lor, \rightarrow \} \in \circ$ and  $S5⊢\neg A \Rightarrow S4 ⊢\neg \Diamond \Box A$?

Comment: The translation is $A'=\Diamond\Box A$ for every formula $A$. It does not analyze the formula by connectives.

Comment: Ok, but say I have $S5⊢A \circ B$,for  $\{\land, \lor, \rightarrow \} \in \circ$ and  $S5 ⊢\neg A$. Would these be expressed in S4 as $\Diamond \Box A \circ \Diamond \Box B$ and $\neg \Diamond \Box A$?

Comment: Ah, I get it. We just preface any S5 formula A with $\Diamond \Box$